# Shell | Array is separating elements containing spaces

Tags: arrays, shell, loops

I have a file containing records like

```
abc def, pqrm, tuv<linebreak>
qwe ett, tyr, rty<line break>
asd fgh, ghj, lkj<line break>
```

I have created an array from first column in above file as below ``

```
TokenName= ($( awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","}; {print $1}' <filename> ))
```

now when I am accessing the element using

```
for tname in "${TokenName[@]}"
do
    echo $tname
done
```

I am expecting output as

```
abc def
qwe ett
asd fgh
```

but it is printing output as

```
abc 
def
qwe 
ett
asd 
fgh
```

Please suggest how can this be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Shell expansion does happen on whitespace. You can avoid awk and do this in shell by looping through the file line by line and appending first column in an array:

```
arr=()

while IFS=, read -r c1 _; do
   arr+=("$c1")
done < file
```

Then test the output array:

```
declare -p arr # running this should emit the following line as output:
declare -a arr='([0]="abc def" [1]="qwe ett" [2]="asd fgh")'
```